# A start job is running for sys-subsystem-net-devices

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, systemctl

So a while back I was unable to get my wifi to automatically connect in Arch Linux, I looked up some videos and found one that made me do the command `sudo systemctl enable` with something like `netctl-auto@` and then something at the end. Well, I figured out that that didn't work so I ditched it. Now at boot I get a message that loads for 1m30s saying "A start job is running for sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp0s26u1u1.ervice.device". And when I think back to it, when I entered that code earlier, I accidentally put in `sudo systemctl enable netctl-auto@enp0s26u1u1.ervice` because it told me to do that except I messed up and forgot the s in service. Idk what to do, I have tried entering the disable code `sudo systemctl disable netctl-auto@enp0s26u1u1.ervice` and even `sudo systemctl disable netctl-auto@enp0s26u1u1.ervice.device` but nothing is working. Can some one help me unscrew up my computer XD

Thanks!

EDIT:

So I figured it out. For those of you who are having the same kind of starting issues, 1m30s wait because of "A start job is running for sys-subsystem-net-devices...", start up your computer, go to the path etc/systemd/system and look around in the folders there for the name of whatever is attempting to start. My problem was located in a folder called multi-user.target.wants . You will have to open a terminal there and run sudo rm (name of file) in order to remove it. Hope this conversation I had with myself helps someone XD

Comment: This conversation did help, indeed! Thanks :)

Comment: thank you *so much* for this!  I'd been hunting for an hour with long-winded tutorials which didn't address the problem.  Hunting in /etc/systemd/system did the trick.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

This can happen when you install a new network device in your machine, which may cause other network devices to change their names. In my case, for instance, my wired card's name changed from `enp3s0` to `enp4s0`, which caused a start job for `sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp3s0.device` to delay the boot sequence.

As the OP suggests, go to `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` and look for the offending device name. It can be in the filename, or in a file's contents. Use

```
grep enp3s0 *
```

To search in every file's contents. Edit the file in question and correct the device's name. Reboot and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

In recent Ubuntu, it uses Netplan to configure network interface. You can see it in the netplan config file, such as `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`.

If one of the interfaces specified there has `optional: false`, then boot process will wait until that interface is available. And if the interface is no longer available, it will wait until it times out.

Specifically, this happened to me on a Raspberry PI where I disabled WiFi, but forgot to remove the config from netplan (it was set to `optional: false`), so the boot was waiting to time out.